# Coutinous Integration of Xamarin Android

Tags: android, msbuild, xamarin.android, mdtool

I'm recently working on automatic building of android in Xamarin. I came across some guides and discussion but couldn't find a solution yet.

I realized that the walkthrough in reference (1) guided to use mdtool on iOS, however, msbuild on android. This gives me the problem due to different project configuration in some project. For instance, project A has configuration "Debug", "Beta", "Release", however project B only has "Debug" and "Release", and project A is the startup project.

In the situation above, let's say I would like to build project A with configuration "Debug", is has no problem as the configuration would just pass to all dependant projects. The problem comes when building "Beta" configuration in Project A. There is no way for me to inform the MSBuild that please use "Release" for project B and a complaint was thrown from MSBuild.

Also, I tried to build individual project without by supplying flag of /p:BuildProjectReferences=false, it seems that the dependant project is still build and same error was thrown.

I think I almost out of solution here and looking for expert from here. Any helps are welcome, thank you~

Exact command used for build: 
"%MS_BUILD_PATH%\MSBuild.exe" /t:PackageForAndroid /p:BuildProjectReferences=false /p:Configuration=Beta "%SOLUTION_PATH%\%SOLUTION_NAME%

Reference:

1. http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/jenkins_walkthrough/
2. http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2114/create-apk-from-command-line